# Number of Points on an Elliptic Curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

If I have an elliptic curve

$$E: y^2 = x^3 + bx + c$$, with $b, c$ integers mod some prime $p$.

And $x^3 + bx + c$ has at least one root mod $p$.

How can I show that the number of points on the curve is even?

Comment: this is the number of points over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Yes it is over $\mathbb{F}_p$. So far I have that since half the numbers mod $p$ are a square, and there is at least 1 root(which will yield only 1 $y$ value), and also counting $\infty$, but am not sure how to formally show that the number is even.

Answer (score 2):

The number of points is $1+\sum_{x\in \mathbb F_p}\left(\left(\frac{x^3+ax+b}{p}\right)+1\right)$, where $\left(\frac{x^3+ax+b}{p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol modulo $p$. If $x$ is not a root of $x^3+ax+b$, the term inside the sum is either $0$ or $2$. Otherwise, it is $1$. If $x^3+ax+b$ has a root, then it has either $1$ or $3$ roots and the sum is odd, which makes the number of points even.

More conceptually, if that polynomial has a root than $E$ has a rational $2$-torsion points, and therefore $2$ divides the order of $E(\mathbb F_p)$.

Comment: If the polynomial $x^3+ax+b$ has no root, why can't all the terms inside the sum be all $0$ (which would make the number of points be $1$, that is, an odd number…)?

Comment: If $x^3+ax+b$ has no rational root, then the term inside the sum is always 0 or two, so the sum is even and the curve has an odd number of points. Which of course can be seen also in the following way: since $E(\mathbb F_p)$ is a finite abelian group, its order is even if and only if there exists an element of order 2, this happens if and only if $E$ has a rational $2$-torsion point, that is equivalent to ask that $x^3+ax+b$ has a rational root.

Comment: Ok, I haven't read the question of the OP correctly. But if $x^3+ax+b$ has no root over $\Bbb F_p$, I think that the number of points of the elliptic curve should be $>1$ (if $p>3$) ; how do I prove it? (You might be able to answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2897078/elliptic-curve-has-points-over-finite-fields)

Comment: Are there similar results where number of points can be given modulo some number?