# Elliptic curve has points over finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with affine equation
$$y^2 = x^3+ax+b$$
where $a,b \in \Bbb Z$. Let $P$ be the set of prime numbers not dividing $ab$.

Can we prove directly that if $p \in P$ is at least $5$, then $E(\Bbb F_p) \neq \{ [0:1:0] \}$ ? This should follow from Hasse's bound
$$|E(\Bbb F_p)| \geq p+1-2\sqrt p > 1, \quad\forall p \geq 5$$
But my question is about a much weaker statement, so there is probably an easier proof.

Comment: Yes, you can use the formula with the Legendre symbol for the number of points on the curve. This is much easier.

Comment: For $p=3$ we cannot assume that our elliptic curve has short Weierstrass form.

Comment: The number of points is
$$N=1+\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}\left(1+\left(\frac{x^3+ax+p}p\right)\right).$$ The first $1$ comes from the point at infinity, and the $1$ in the summand comes from the fact that the number of solutions of $y^2=v$ is equal to $1+\left(\dfrac v p\right)$. Of course, it is simpler to write
$$N=p+1+\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}\left(\frac{x^3+ax+b}p\right).$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515578/

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : thank you for your comment. How can I see that $N>1$ in all cases?

Comment: @DietrichBurde : how can we see that $N = p+1+\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_p}\left(\frac{x^3+ax+b}p\right) > 1$ for $p>3$? This is equivalent to find some $x$ such that $\left(\frac{x^3+ax+b}p\right) = 1$ or $0$.

Comment: In _DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS WITH SPECIAL REFERENCE TO ELLIPTIC CURVES_ by J. W. S. CASSELS, theorem 15.1 (F. K. Schmidt) states that all smooth cubic curves over finite fields have points defined over it (hence are elliptic curves [recall that if they are plane curves, this implies genus 1]).